# Trying to divide two numbers keep getting Dividebyzero error

Tags: c#

Ok so here is my problem, I have this code:

```
decRatio = _intNumofRooms /intTotal;
if (decRatio > 1/6) {
    MessageBox.Show("There can't be more than six people in the same room!", "Trump's Hotel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    txtNumOfChildren.Focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
```

I have a hotel that can only accept 6 adults per room. The adults are (inTotal) and now I am trying to divide the number of rooms by how many adults I have to get a ratio, then if the ratio is bigger than 1/6 I am trying to show that message box demanding they enter an amount where no more than six people can be in one room, but keep getting the dividebyzeroexception error. Another ways of having such ratio or how do I solve this please?

Comment: Are you sure `inTotal` is not zero?

Comment: Please put your code in the question itself, not as an external link to a picture.

Comment: Copy-paste your code as text. Don't use images. Show where `intTotal` come from

Comment: Where do you define inTotal? How is inTotal defined? Pleased don't take screenshots of code, post it here using code formatting.

Comment: @itsme86 but that's not dividing by zero.

Comment: First your math is backward, don't divide rooms by guests, divide guests into rooms, then you end up with checking for > 6, as you have it now, it will allow 6 or more guests per room, if the math worked since 1/7 < 1/6 but 1/5 > 1/6. Your message will pop up when there are less than 6 people in one room, with what you wrote there.

Answer (score 7):

Integer division produces an integer in C#.  `1/6` is a division of two integers, so it produces zero.  If you want to produce fractions then do the math in doubles:

```
double ratio = (double)numberOfRooms / (double)total;
if (ratio > 1.0 / 6.0) ...
```

I don't know if that's causing your divide by zero error, but the code you posted is obviously wrong, so start by fixing it.

Also, do not name things in C# based on what type they are.  It is not `intNumberOfRooms`.  It's `numberOfRooms`.  It's not `intTotal`, it's `totalNumberOfGuests`.

Also, your math is simply wrong. Suppose there are six people and six rooms. That is a ratio of 6/6 which is greater than 1/6, and so that is a policy violation?  You've got this completely backwards.

You would do better to avoid ratios entirely.  You can do the work in integers like this:

```
if (totalNumberOfGuests > 6 * totalNumberOfRooms) ...
```

Don't do a division if you can do a multiplication instead.

Next: you have conflated your user interface with your business policy code. Suppose you decide to change the limit from six to five; how many places in the code do you have to change?  You have to not only change the math but also the error string.  Encapsulate this logic into a function that determines whether policy is violated, and if so, what the message should be. Keep your business policy code *far away* from your user interface code. Can you see how to reorganize the code to better separate your concerns?

Finally, before you post here again you should read this:

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

and come back when you have a *specific question about code*.  "I wrote a buggy program that I can't fix" is not a *question*.

Comment: I would also suggest that `total` is also checked for being zero before it is used in that operation, setting ratio to zero if it is.

Comment: Thank you, the professor wants the names that way and i personally don't like that way either...